# Single line statement to print range of numbers on a single line

Tags: python-2.7

I am a beginner in Python. I would like to know if there is any alternative approach to print a range of numbers in a single line apart from the one given below. Is there any single line statement which can print the range of numbers and which runs faster than the code given below?

```
r=int(raw_input())
for i in range(1,r+1):
    print i,
```

Comment: Why don't you simply write a function that does that? Some complicated code that achieves that in one line will probably make your code less readable. As for speed, at best you can shave off nanoseconds.

Comment: Well this a problem statement from one of the online coding sites. The speed and the single line statement were the constraints put by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the join() method

```
print "".join([str(i) for i in range(1,int(raw_input())+1)])
```

or you can use the print_function from **future** module

```
print(*range(1,int(raw_input())+1),sep='')
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to convert it to a string or use a separator. Just unpacking the list should be enough.

```
print ([i for i in range(1,r+1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

As Neo notes, You can print the range all on one line by:

```
print ([i for i in range(1,r+1)])
```

and if you want just the integers instead of a python list, just use:

```
print (*[i for i in range(1,r+1)])
```

to unpack the list.

Comment: Without a `__future__` import, your addition won't work on Python 2; unpacking only applies to function calls, and the Python 2 `print` statement isn't a function call (the parentheses are irrelevant here, they're just grouping a single item).

Comment: I neglected to read the OP's post again before just extending Neo's. Didn't notice he was using 2.7! Thanks...